# Firebase.initializeApp(); and FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken() throws android native exceptions

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I'm using FlutterFire Cli to configure my firebase project
it was working and i hadn't change any single line of code
and i have an online version of the application on google play

then the deployed version is stopped working and after debugging
it start showing at any time the app is trying to initialize firebase project or getToken
 `Failed to get FIS auth token`

```
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(GmsRpc.java:260)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.startRpc(GmsRpc.java:222)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.getToken(GmsRpc.java:180)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$blockingGetToken$10$FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:610)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FirebaseMessaging$1AYfBMlbEOJoTvXNS_TEZqpK2SY.start(Unknown Source:6)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(RequestDeduplicator.java:67)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:606)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:392)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FirebaseMessaging$m5Uvt0n8P9zrx-ecASLTQKzoABQ.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532): Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:153)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:530)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:385)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2$FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:374)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at com.google.firebase.installations.-$$Lambda$FirebaseInstallations$VZq1h0TBcWNH8Y5yY86ujrFFyLo.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseMessaging(31532):     ... 1 more
Lost connection to device
```

I'm using

firebase_core: ^1.20.0
firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1

After Doing Flutter Clean and Deleting Build Folder it shows

```
error when communicating with firebase installation , server api , Http response [ 403 forbidden:
```

Although im not using any vpn

I've tried many solutions like creating new firebase project via flutterfire and still showing me the same errors

Any Solutions ? and thanks

Comment: You can try with older version of Firebase_core package. I got solution from that.

Comment: Also, Please ensure that version is changed in pubspec.lock file in project.

Comment: @RenikShiroya how to ensure that ? i usually do flutter clean and pub get is that enough?

Comment: No, When you changed the version and run fultter pub get. After that, Please check the version of Firebase_core in pubspec.lock because sometimes there is still old version

Comment: @RenikShiroya you were right ! firebase_core in pubspec.lock still 1.20.0

should i change it manually  to new version or deleting the file and generating new one is better ?

Comment: You can delete it.

Comment: @RenikShiroya nothing changed

Comment: Facing the same problem!! any Update?

Comment: @AliIzadyar im in syria and i can tell you after trying alot ... its now forbidden for android devices to get token for the first time without vpn ... this problem has appeared for 3 days .. 
so i think we can do nothing about that

Comment: Yeah I now realize that is the exact problem. I live in Iran and this problem is reported by others too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I’m living in Syria, and it has become forbidden to call `getToken` **for the first time** without a VPN, at least for Android devices.

Comment: have the same problem from iran

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when one of the dependancies of firebase is out of date. You Should update all the firebase packages to their newest version in the pubspec.yaml . (If you do not need to use a specific version for deployment).
You can check out the newest versions on pub.dev

Comment: i had updated all the packages .. nothing changed
assume it would work .. then what should i do to the deployed version?

Comment: Maybe This post can help you out as it has tackled this issue already! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635672/e-firebaseinstanceid-failed-to-get-fis-auth-token

Comment: i've seen this post before 
there is no mention how to solve this in flutter app in this post

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDKs depend on a new internal infrastructure service, called FIS (the Firebase Installations Service) since [February 27 2020](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-02-27) and it's now required to connect to this API to register client's device and get a token.
So, Firebase will request something like this (https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$project_identifier/installations/?key=$api_key) to do so.
After investigating you can see that this process it done by google-play-services and called from Firebase-Plugin as shown here :

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/c6cc8c5d4a00518033a6f281486c9610b821e1c4/firebase-messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/GmsRpc.java#L260

So, I Think if you can edit the plugin to send the requests to a proxy server then to the FIS API you can go around this issue.

Unfortunately,I can confirm that the FIS API now gives 403 error in Syria.

Hope google resolve this issue soon...