# Failed to get FIS auth token in wear_os_emulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os, android-wear-notification

**Integrating firebase notification in wear_os and android emulator as well, notification working fine in the android emulator but got this error while running in wear_os emulator.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635672/e-firebaseinstanceid-failed-to-get-fis-auth-token

Comment: @debugger, I tried this solution as well, but still have not gotten the answer.